# TinyMCE - how to select tags node from the place where the caret is?

Tags: tags, tinymce, api, visual-editor

**Hello to everyone!**

I've been wracking my brains, trying to find a solution for this. And here is what I have.

**Task:**

I want to detect in which tag my cursor(caret) is standing, and then to select those tags with the text inside. I've tried to do this using **TinyMCE API** but to no avail, since I don't quite really understand how it works with Wordpress fully.

The [style_formats](https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Styles) feature already has what I want to do. It behaves exactly like I want it to be. It changes the styling of the whole block doesn't matter where my cursor is. But I decided not to use it because I want all my styles to be on the same custom button.

---

**Example:**

For example I have some text between **h1** tags `<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>`. For instance, I put my cursor after the word `ipsum` and in return, I want to get the whole line with the tags.

---

**What I already have:**

I already have the code that changes the selected text. But I want also to know how to apply the change to the block of text where my cursor is standing.

```
(function() {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('test_tc_button', function( editor, url ) {
        //console.log(url);
        editor.addButton( 'test_tc_button', {
            title: 'test toolbar',
            type: 'menubutton',
            icon: 'icon test-own-icon',
            menu: [

            // Standard Quote Section
            {
                text: 'Quote',
                icon: 'icon custom-icon-quote',
                onclick: function() {                        
                   var selection = '';                       
                   selection = editor.selection.getContent({
                        'format': 'text'    
                   });
                   if ( selection.length === 0 ) {
                       alert('No text has been selected!');
                        return;
                   }
                   editor.insertContent('<p class="blockquote">' + selection + '</p>');
                }
            }

           ]
        });
    });
})();
```

Thankful in advance!